How does the Go etree XML package define "siblings" and "children"?
I have an XML struct like this.
<Process>
     <Name> Process1 </Name>
     <SQLFile> aSQLFile.sql </SQLFile>
     <SQLText> select * from Items <SQLText>
     <Mode> 2 </Mode>
<Process>

I am using beevik/etree to work with this.
In the sample code below, a list of this XML struct is called elems. I am calling this code to walk through elems in an XML document:
for elemA := range elems.FindElements("//Name") {
    elemB:=elemA.FindElement(//SQLFile){
       doSomething(elemB)
}

This code works - doSomething(elemB) does what it is supposed to do, but according to the etree comments on FindElement, it should fail. elemB should be nil:

FindElement returns the first element matched by the XPath-like
'path'  string. The function returns nil if no child element is found
using the  path.

According to that comment, elemB:=elemA.FindElement(//SQLFile) should return nil, because <SQLFile> is a sibling of <Name>, not a child. <Name> has no child.
Why isn't elemA.FindElement(//SQLFile) returning nil in this code?

Provided your code is correct, and etree documents the behavior of // like it behaves in X-Path (I mean, its docs state «… lightweight XPath-like query APIs»; emphasis mine), then it looks like the package has a bug: the double-slash in X-Path should search the subgraph of elements starting at the specified node. Also note that the tests are apparently using .// the notation to search down the current node.

@kostix - I've gone over that code several times and didn't even want to use FindElement in that situation, knowing that the second node is a sibling and not a child. In the end I tried it and it worked - to my surprise. I tend to think that it is indeed a bug in the code or a a mistake in the documentation.

@kostix - from what I can cull (I'm no Go expert) the tests there appear to be using both // and .// - I will test my code using  .//- I think that should fail as expected.

@kostix - see answer. I misunderstood the etree comments.

The comment reads: // FindElement returns the first element matched by the XPath-like 'path'
// string. The function returns nil if no child element is found using the
// path. It panics if an invalid path string is supplied. // is part of the comment. To get the child .// must be used. // returns a sibling.

The etree comments are not quite clear here, and I misuderstood them.
The function returns nil if no child element is found using the
// path. is a misreading. // returns a sibling, not a child, as the XPath would indicate. But // is part of the comment, not the XPath code itself as indicated by the space before  path.
.
.//returns a child only.
(Thanks to @kostix for pointing me in the right direction in the comments on the question.)
